# What order are Pikmin retrieved from an Onion?

Tags: pikmin

When I retrieve Pikmin from an Onion at the start of a day, I noticed that the Pikmin will often be at different [stages of maturity](https://www.pikminwiki.com/Maturity). Some will have flowers, while others will still be leaves. This makes me believe if a Pikmin with a flower is deposited, it will still have a flower when it is retrieved.

How does the game determine which Pikmin to give if you have multiple Pikmin at different stages of maturity? For example, let's say I have a I have a red onion with 90 Pikmin. 30 with leaves, 30 with buds, and 30 with flowers. If I retrieve 30 Pikmin, what stage of evolution will they be at? Will it prioritize flowersn and give me 30 flower Pikmin, will I get 10 of each type, or will I get some other combination?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Pikipedia](https://www.pikminwiki.com/Onion#Withdrawing_and_retrieving), flower Pikmin are prioritized when withdrawing.

> In the case that there are Pikmin of multiple maturities, flower Pikmin will be withdrawn first, until there are no more left, in which case bud Pikmin will be withdrawn, and finally leaf Pikmin.